# Dojo 1.6.1 dijit form onSubmit event cancels others

Tags: javascript, dojo, submit, dom-events

I have a Dojo 1.6.1 (dijit) form with a connection on the submit event. 
The form will be submitted with AJAX. 
The problem is that when i use `dojo.stopEvent` on the submit event it stops the triggering of the `onChange` events for the other inputs (dijits).

In other words: after the submit event occurs I explicitly stop it and send the data with AJAX. After that the `onChange` event for the inputs cannot be triggered neither by changing the inputs value or programmatically calling `dijit.byId('someDijit').onChange()`.

Any ideas what is the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, my bad. The function was called correctly, however another function executed in the `onChange` wasn't firing.

EDIT:

And the fault was a function with the same name(as the function to be called inside `onChange`), introduced later in the script.